# Dev console log entries are hidden in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, logging

I have a library of various functions that I use for my websites. I include the base/core library in the `<head>` of my document, then I load more scripts that extend the core in other part of the doc (usually at the end). My library has a log function that calls `console.log()`. It logs various information such as when the library has started and ended logging, when another script is loaded, when an error is caught, etc.

**I can NOT post my script - it is internal to the company I work for**

The scripts execute successfully, but my log entries aren't being displayed in my developer console in Firefox version 29.0.1 for Mac OS X 10.9.1. Sometimes it displays all entries, sometimes only a couple, usually NONE.

The only thing I get are some JS warnings.

```
16:02:49.712 Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:3
16:02:49.807 Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. requestNotifier.js:64
```

[image]

Here's when it actually logs properly, but there should be about 15 log entries BEFORE all of the ones after the warnings. (note I enabled persistent log for this screenshot)

[image]

Below is what is logged in Chrome 35. Only a couple of lines from the screenshot are SOMETIMES logged in Firefox. Bizarre.

[image]

I've checked all of the dropdown options and all JS and Logging options are enabled (plus Security and some Net ones).

I can call `console.log()` from the console itself (after all scripts have loaded and run) and it logs as expected.

I have increased my console log limit from 200 to 500 and tested.

When I run the same script(s) in Chrome, they display fine as expected. All log entries are there. The same goes for Firebug, a Firefox extension that gives me an alternative developer console.

Does Firefox do some funky caching or grouping in the dev console?

**I can NOT post my script - it is internal to the company I work for**

Comment: Are you sure your JavaScript is actually running as expected in Firefox? Could you post your JavaScript and ideally create a JSFiddle.net demo which demonstrates this problem?

Comment: I cannot. The library is internal to the company. You can see the JavaScript is working in the 2nd screenshot. I have updated my question to mention this.

Comment: @tsilik_ That did it! I disabled all addons and enabled them one by one. When I enabled Firebug, I was greeted by a new JS warning: `The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.` Apparently Firebug replaces `console.log()`, but only sometimes?

Comment: If you answer the original question I'll mark it as the selected one when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by disabling one by one your firefox add-ons. You can do quick testing for console.log from [getfirebug.com/tests/head/console/api/log.html](http://getfirebug.com/tests/head/console/api/log.html). One or more of your add-ons is causing the conflict.

I had faced the same issue from Nimbus Screen Capture Add-on, which should be irrelevant to console stuff whatsoever.